# How to manage shared code between Spring Boot projects?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, continuous-integration

So I work at a company that uses spring for the backend and GitLab for CI/CD. We currently have 2 spring projects that use a substantial amount of shared code. Mainly JPA repositories, Models, DTO's, and services. We are looking for a solution that will allow us to more easily share the changes made to the shared code between our projects. For instance, if we create a new query in a repository in project A, we want to be able to have it in project B without resorting to copying and pasting code.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You can write your own custom starters.

Comment: Create project C which holds the common code.  The CI pipeline publishes the jar from project C to an internal maven repository.  Projects A and B use project C as a dependency.  Use version numbers if projects A and B cannot immediately consume the latest version of project C.  If projects A and B can immediately consume the latest version of project C, then have a CI rule that a successful build of project C triggers a build of projects A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe @Andrew remark is good enough to handle this case, so just to explain it in detail will be sharing few steps that could be performed.

Create a new project(***common-util***) that could have spring boot capabilities or not depend on what kind of items you wanna segregate from your project A. Otherwise, it could be a normal java project with spring capabilities if you are looking for DI or other items like JPA and all.

Now add this project as a dependency in your project A and B, now for every change in your common-util you just need to update the latest version in your project A and B.

**Sample POM for common-util:**

```
<groupId>com.xyz.groupid</groupId>  
<artifactId>common-util</artifactId>  
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

**Sample POM for project A:**

```
<groupId>com.xyz.groupid</groupId>  
<artifactId>A</artifactId>  
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependency>  
  <groupId>com.xyz.groupid</groupId>  
  <artifactId>common-util</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Sample POM for project B:**

```
<groupId>com.xyz.groupid</groupId>  
<artifactId>B</artifactId>  
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependency>  
  <groupId>com.xyz.groupid</groupId>  
  <artifactId>common-util</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```